# How do I interpret java assembly?

Tags: java

```
  // Method descriptor #8 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public EGLConfig();
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [1]
     4  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     7  dup
     8  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
    10  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
    13  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 4]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: this index: 0 type: javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig
}
```

Anyone can "read" this?

Comment: If you have class file you could use this: http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/

Comment: What do you have difficulty with? I can tell you its the same as `public EGLConfig() { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); }` but how does that help you?

Answer (score 5):

The [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html) documents the meaning of Java bytecode instructions and how the JVM processes them.

It looks something like this, when translated to Java:

```
// Constructor of class EGLConfig
public EGLConfig() {
    super();
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

Line by line:

```
 0  aload_0 [this]
 1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [1]
```

Pushes `this` (reference to the current object) on the stack and calls the constructor of the superclass, which is `Object`.

```
 4  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
 7  dup
 8  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
10  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
```

Creates a new `RuntimeException` object and calls its constructor which takes a `String`; it passes in the string `"Stub!"`.

```
13  athrow
```

Throws the `RuntimeException`.